# How to reference query parameters inside a Kong's plugin configuration?

Tags: query-string, kong, kong-plugin

I want to implement a simple redirect using Kong's request-termination & response-transformer plugins. The plugins mostly works, but I have an issue with handling query parameters.

My configuration for the plugins is similar to this (note: I'm using Kong in DB-less mode):

```yaml
services:
- name: my-redirects
  url: http://localhost:8080/
  routes:
  - name: redirect-route
    paths:
    - /context$
    - /$
  plugins:
  - name: request-termination
    config:
      status_code: 301
      message: Redirect to main page...
  - name: response-transformer
    config:
      add:
        headers:
        - Location:/context/
```

I want to obtain the following behaviour:

- User visits http://localhost:8000/  -> redirected to `/context/`
- User visits http://localhost:8000/context -> redirected to `/context/`
- User visits http://localhost:8000/?param=value -> redirected to `/context/?param=value`
- User visits http://localhost:8000/context?param=value -> redirected to `/context/?param=value`

Basically both `/` and `/context` requests should be redirected to `/context/` (with a final slash) but **query parameters should be preserved**.

How can I modify the configuration:

```yaml
add:
  headers:
  - Location:/context/
```

to include query parameters matched in the request? I expect to be able to do something like:

```yaml
add:
  headers:
  - Location:/context/$query_params
```

Comment: What about write your own plugin to handle that ?

Comment: @Ôrel This seems like one of the most basic functionalities ever. I can't believe there isn't some way to deal with this without having to write code in Lua. Anyway if you can give an example plugin go ahead and answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

What we are using to solve this on kong running in kubernetes is to use an ingress `Exact` rule coupled with a `pre-function` plugin. It should be easy to adapt it to the non-k8s yaml config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress-redirect
    konghq.com/plugins: foo-redirect
spec:
  ...
  rules:
    - host: myhost.example
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /foo/bar  # redirect /foo/bar to /foo/bar/ via plugin above
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              ...
```

and then plugin:

```yaml
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: foo-redirect
plugin: pre-function
config:
  access:
    - kong.response.exit(301, '', {['Location'] = '/foo/bar/'})
```

You can also play with [kong.request](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/pdk/kong.request/#main) interface if you need to e.g. pass the original query params on the redirect.

It's a bit convoluted but also did not find a simpler way.